# How to retrieve two different XML tags using "FROM OPENXML" in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, openxml

I have an XML like this:

```
   <OWNER>
      <NAME>Lucas</NAME>
      <EMAIL>lucas@sample.com</EMAIL>
    <OWNER>
    <ITENS>
      <MEMBER Nitem="1">
           <NAME>Alex</NAME>
           <EMAIL>alex@sample.com</EMAIL>
      </MEMBER>
      <MEMBER Nitem="2">
           <NAME>Jane</NAME>
           <EMAIL>jane@sample.com</EMAIL>
      </MEMBER>
    <ITENS>
```

My stored procedure already gets all the `Members` correctly using:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp_XML(id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, namespaceuri, datatype, prev, text)
   SELECT 
       id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, namespaceuri, datatype, prev, text
   FROM 
       OPENXML(@_IdXML,'//Member',2)
```

but I also want to insert at this same temporary table **#Temp_XML** the Owner values (it has the same attributes, name and email).

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - using the **native** XQuery support in SQL Server (2005 and newer):

```
DECLARE @Id_XML XML ='<OWNER>
      <NAME>Lucas</NAME>
      <EMAIL>lucas@sample.com</EMAIL>
    </OWNER>
    <ITENS>
      <MEMBER Nitem="1">
           <NAME>Alex</NAME>
           <EMAIL>alex@sample.com</EMAIL>
      </MEMBER>
      <MEMBER Nitem="2">
           <NAME>Jane</NAME>
           <EMAIL>jane@sample.com</EMAIL>
      </MEMBER>
    </ITENS>'

SELECT
    OwnerName = xc.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    OwnerEmail = xc.value('(EMAIL)[1]', 'varchar(250)'),
    MemberItem = xc2.value('@Nitem', 'int'),
    MemberName = xc2.value('(NAME)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    MemberEMail = xc2.value('(EMAIL)[1]', 'varchar(250)')
FROM
    @Id_XML.nodes('/OWNER') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    @Id_XML.nodes('/ITENS/MEMBER') AS XT2(XC2)
```

Gives an output of:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use //Owner and //Member with FROM OPENXML without search twice the XML?

Comment: @Mucida: you can't - if you use `//....`, then you're searching the whole document - twice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way to do it and it worked as well.

```
INSERT INTO #Temp_XML(id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, namespaceuri, datatype, prev, text)
SELECT id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, namespaceuri, datatype, prev, text
FROM 
       OPENXML(@_IdXML,'//Member',2)

INSERT INTO #Temp_XML(id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, namespaceuri, datatype, prev, text)
SELECT id, parentid, nodetype, localname, prefix, namespaceuri, datatype, prev, text
FROM 
       OPENXML(@_IdXML,'//Owner',2)
```

Just putting **'//'** and the name of the XML tag, OPENXML can find it and insert the values into the temporary table, it doesn't matter what position the tag has on the tree.

Comment: Yes, it will *work* - but by using the `//..` notation twice, you're effectively searching the **whole** XML document **twice** - not terribly efficient by any means...

Comment: So how do I insert in just one serach both tags? (owner and member)... I am looking something like 
OPENXML(@_IdXML,'//Member' OR '//Owner',2)